# Getting placeholder text in asp:TextBox from a code behind field with <% and %>

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am having a textbox like

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" ID="txtFoo" runat="server"
    placeholder='<%=txtStartWriteToSearchCustomer %>' />
```

and the code behind contains

```
protected string txtStartWriteToSearchCustomer = "Start typing";
```

However, the textbox will get the place holder

> 

instead of

> Start typing

Omitting the apostrophes and instead having `placeholder=<%=txtStartWriteToSearchCustomer %>` makes the whole tag invalid and `placeholder="<%=txtStartWriteToSearchCustomer %>"` is also outputting the text verbatimly.

How do I put the string in the field into the placeholder without writing an assign statement in the code behind?

## edit

I have successfully used `placeholder=<%#txtStartWriteToSearchCustomer %>` and put the line `DataBind();` first in `Page_Load`. That seems to disturb the data binding of other elements on the web page in a way that I do not really understand. You have to do things in a correct order. I do not want to use that approach because it seems to add complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in code behind

```
txtFoo.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Start typing");
```

Comment: That counts as an "assign statement" in the code behind.

Comment: I am using a data annotation on the fields with those strings so I can enumerate them and perform translations of them.